# Init method gets called twice in @Viewscoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, annotations, postconstruct

I am using schedule component of Primefaces. I am filling it with values from database and when the user selects sth from the selectonemenu an ajax event is triggered (I tried to put just the related code, if there is sth missing pls remind me):

**xhtml:**

```
 <h:outputText value="Scope :" />
 <h:selectOneMenu id="scope" value="#{scheduleView.scope}">                    
   <f:selectItems value="#{lookup.scopeCombo}"/>
   <p:ajax process="scope" update="schedule, scheduleForm, scheduleFormPG" listener="#{scheduleView.changeScopeType()}"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu> 

<p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleView.model}" editable="true"/>
```

**Backing bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ScheduleView implements Serializable { 

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init ");
        scopeChange();                
    } 

    public void scopeChange(String scope){
        System.out.println("scopeChange ");
        model.clear();
        events = (List<Event>) commonServis.bringEverythingByCriteria(Event.class, "scope" , scope);   
        for(int i= 0; i<events.size();i++){
        model.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(events.get(i).getAd(), events.get(i).getStartDate(),events.get(i).getEndDate()));
    }

    public void changeScopeType() {
    System.out.println("changeScopeType ");
        scopeChange (scope);
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Init
scopeChange
```

When the user changes the value in the selectonemenu:

```
changeScopeType
Init
scopeChange
```

It is supposed to go into `init` method just once. But after the `changeScopeType` function is triggered it gets into the `init` method and fills the schedule with unrelated data. I thought it might be related to `@Postconstruct` annotation but I couldn't find any related explanation. Can anyone understand the reason and offer a solution?

Here is the full page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://prime.primefaces.org/ui"
                template="templates/layout.xhtml"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <ui:define name="title">#{labels.schedule}</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="scheduleForm">
            <h:panelGrid id="scheduleFormPG">
                <p:growl id="msgs" />
                <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false">
                    <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                </p:dialog>
                <p:dialog showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false"
                      header="warning" widgetVar="confirmationErase" appendToBody="true" modal="true">
                    <h:outputText value="Are you sure?"/>
                    <br/>
                    <p:commandButton  value="Yes" actionListener="#{scheduleView.deleteEvent(AE)}"
                                     update="msgs, scheduleFormPG, schedule, wrapperPanel"
                                     onstart="statusDialog.show(),confirmationErase.hide()"
                                     oncomplete="statusDialog.hide(), eventDialog.hide()" process="@parent, scope" />
                    <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="confirmationErase.hide()" type="button" />
                </p:dialog>                
                <h:outputText value="scope :" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="scope" value="#{scheduleView.scope}">                    
                    <f:selectItems value="#{lookup.scopeTypeCombo}"/>
                    <p:ajax process="scope" update="schedule, scheduleForm, scheduleFormPG" listener="#{scheduleView.changeScopeType()}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>                
             </h:panelGrid>            
            <p:schedule onDateSelectUpdate="wrapperPanel" 
                        onEventSelectUpdate="wrapperPanel" onEventSelectComplete="eventDialog.show()" eventSelectListener="#{scheduleView.onEventSelect}" 
                        onDateSelectComplete="eventDialog.show();"  dateSelectListener="#{scheduleView.onDateSelect}" id="schedule" value="#{scheduleView.model}" editable="true"/>
            <p:dialog id="dialog111" widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Information" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
                <p:panel id="wrapperPanel">                    
                    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">   
                        <h:outputLabel for="eventName" value="Event Name *: " />
                        <p:inputText id="eventName" value="#{scheduleView.event.title}" required="true"/>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Start Date:" />
                        <p:calendar id="sKalender" value="#{scheduleView.event.startDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
                        </p:calendar>
                        <h:outputLabel value="End Date:" />
                        <p:calendar id="eKalender" value="#{scheduleView.event.endDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
                        </p:calendar>
                        <h:outputLabel value="All Day:" />
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleView.event.allDay}" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="scope: " />
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="scopeChoice" value="#{scheduleView.event.scope}">                    
                            <f:selectItems value="#{lookup.scopeTypeCombo}"/>
                         </h:selectOneMenu>                         
                          <p:commandButton onclick="confirmationErase.show()" oncomplete="eventDialog.hide()" update="wrapperPanel, msgs, schedule" type="reset" value="Delete" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleView.addEvent(AE)}" process="@parent, scope" update="schedule wrapperPanel msgs scheduleForm" oncomplete="eventDialog.hide();"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:dialog>
           </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Are you referencing the `#{scheduleView}` anywhere in a taghandler like JSTL `<c:if>` or in `id` or `binding` attributes of JSF components? See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215098/view-scoped-bean-recreated-on-post-when-url-parameters-not-used/14216971#14216971

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is not in JSTL <c:if> or in id or binding attributes. But it is used like: value="#{scheduleView.scope}" or actionListener="#{scheduleView.deleteEvent(AE)} or listener="#{scheduleView.changeKapsamTipi() or rendered="#{scheduleView.takvimTuruYillik}" or eventSelectListener="#{scheduleView.onEventSelect}" inside p:commandButton, p:schedule, p:dataTable and h:selectonemenu components.

Comment: Well, then I don't see any reasonable causes. Are you using Spring? I recall the JSF partial state saving mechanism to somehow break like that when Spring is installed, causing all view scoped beans to behave like request scoped ones. You'd need to explicitly force `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` context parameter to `true`.

Comment: yes I am using Spring. I tried turning off the partial state saving as you mentioned but it did not work..

Comment: Regarding your post (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) shouldn't I be using <ui:define> also?

Comment: It's merely for templating.

Comment: try adding to your bean `@PreDestroy
 public void destory(){
  System.out.println("why ow why");
 }` and see when its being destroyed...

Comment: @lamostreta , also , try to replace `actionListener="#{scheduleView.deleteEvent(AE)}` with `actionListener="#{scheduleView.deleteEvent}` , cause `actionListener` not supposed to receive any arguments...

Comment: I added.. but I didn't get it in the output.. I also log out from the system to see if it is triggered in that case, still no good.

Comment: OK, I will also try that..

Comment: @lamostreta You mean that being is being created twice , without being destroyed in between ? You can also try removing references to `scheduleView` from your xhtmls...

Comment: :P I have 1 unrelated question. When you use `update="schedule, scheduleForm, scheduleFormPG"`, it still can work? I thought the syntax for `update` attribute does not have commas.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, but the problem was totally another thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line of code:

```
<p:ajax process="scope" update="schedule, scheduleForm, scheduleFormPG" listener="#{scheduleView.changeScopeType()}"/>
```

update was refreshing the whole page, instead it should've only update schedule. When I change it to:

```
update="schedule"
```

the problem solved. 
Thanks everyone for their effort.