# Why viewscoped ManagedBean are eagerly loaded

Tags: spring, jsf

I try to declare JSF managed bean with @Named and @javax.faces.view.ViewScoped annotations in a spring 4.1 application on JSF 2.2.10 (Mojarra) but it seems that the managed beans are eagerly loaded that cause some problems. Someone could say me why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [View-scoped bean recreated on POST with JSF 2.2.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251176/view-scoped-bean-recreated-on-post-with-jsf-2-2-4)

Comment: It's not the same topic. the problem I'm facing is that the beans are loaded eagerly which cause some problems.I assume that it's a spring effect but i would to know if someone had this problem

Comment: It still might be related.  If you you a wrong scope that Spring does not recognize, it might default to a scope that is eagerly loaded. Just like jsf (seems to) default to a requestscope if a wrong scope is used

Comment: If you are using Spring and your JSF beans are also managed by Spring they are now singletons. Spring doesn't know about the `java.faces.view` scopes and ignores them. I would suggest either CDI instead of Spring (or try to get both working together, which isn't a pleasant exercise imho) or use `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` from the `javax.enterprise` package.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think you meant `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` from the `javax.faces` package ;) to avoid mixing CDI with JSF managed beans

Comment: The beans.xml file is missing so spring manage beans and doesn't recognize @javax.faces.view.ViewScoped annotations (ignore it) and consider the singleton scope which is the default spring scope. Moveing the entire application to CDI is not an option for the moment. Thanks.

Comment: @Tarik you are right the ones from the `javax.faces.bean` package are the one.