# Interceptors don't work with JSF managed beans?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, interceptor, managed-bean

I am decide to try `interceptors` My first interceptor binding annotation is

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface WithLog {
  // No parameters required  
}
```

And interceptor class is

```
@Interceptor
@WithLog
public class LogInterceptor {

  @AroundInvoke
  private Object logMethod(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Method " + context.getMethod().getName() + 
        " of class " + context.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " was called.");
    return context.proceed();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  private void construct(InvocationContext context) {
    System.out.println("@Postconstruct of " + 
        context.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName() + " started.");
  }
}
```

So, I want to add simple logging for JSF managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "departmentRootMB")
@ViewScoped
@WithLog
public class DepartmentRootMB implements Serializable {

  long serialVersionUID = 0L;
// . . . properties, methods

}
```

I read, that to enable interceptors I need to create `beans.xml`. I created one in the `WEB-INF` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
    <interceptors>
        <class>ru.edu.pgtk.weducation.interceptors.LogInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

I rebuild project and no effect. Where is the mistake? What I did wrong? I use glassfish 4.1 with it standard components (WELD, EclipseLink, JSF 2.2.7)

Thanks for your time and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Interceptors don't work with JSF managed beans?*

Correct.

Replace JSF bean management facility by CDI bean management facility.

In other words, replace `@ManagedBean` and friends by `@Named` and friends. The JSF bean management facility is on the schedule to be deprecated in favor of CDI in a future Java EE version anyway. This is a good opportunity to migrate now you can.

#### See also:

- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/4347707#4347707)

Comment: I tried to replace `@ManagedBean` to `@Named`, but `@ViewScoped` didnn't work and all beans annotated by `@Named` (as I think) was request scope. How to fight with this behavior? Interesting that in other projects created in same IDE with same Maven and so one there is no souch behavoir. What is this?

Comment: As answered, you also need replace the "friends". In other words, among others also the related scope annotations. Use CDI's `@ViewScoped` instead of JSF's one. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20251176

Comment: Ok, I think, I understand my mistake. Thank you for your posts.