# CDI Bean recreated on every <h:inputtext>ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, cdi

I have multiple `<h:inputtext>` and an ajax in each.
As I change each input the setter is called along with a `@PostContruct` i created for testing. Why is the bean being recreated ever time i change and input?

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Lunch"/><br/>
    <h:inputText id="item0" value="#{bean.item0}" >
       <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
    </h:inputText><br/>
    <h:inputText id="item1" value="#{bean.item1}">
       <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
    </h:inputText><br/>
    <h:inputText id="item2" value="#{bean.item2}">
       <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
    </h:inputText><br/>
</h:form>
```

I have the Bean class as well as getters and setters for each.

```
@Named(value = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    String item0, item1, item2;
    public Bean(){}
    //Getters/Setters
    ....
```

Comment: Post the bean too.

Comment: and why did you tag it java and java-ee and not cdi?

Comment: @Kukeltje flustered in chasing an error in which is not a problem with in other things ive written in JSF/CDI

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using in your project ?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251176/viewscoped-bean-recreated-on-every-postback-request-when-using-jsf-2-2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541813/viewscoped-calls-postconstruct-on-every-postback-request

Comment: Its a duplicated solved by fixing mismatched imports for named annotation.